# How to spot colloquial differences in word strings that are supposed to be the same thing?

Tags: spell-checking

Does anyone know of any useful java libraries that can compare two different strings and return true even if they may have been spelled differently?
In other words, is there a library that can tell the difference between two words that are supposed to be the same yet spelled differently, and differentiate them if they were different?

**Background**:
I'm trying to write a program that accesses a database and retrieves all the port names in it. My task is to write a program that would crawl certain websites that contain
port names, grab it and write it onto a file. with this newly created file, the task is to compare the port names to those we originally have in our database and change it based
on the way it was written on the internet(keeping in mind they are supposedly referring to the same port).
Any help would be useful to me, thanks!

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: NGram Based Spell Correction could be an option...